# Is there a way in lodash to merge an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, lodash

I stuck at merging an array of objects in JavaScript. I want to merge them into one object use either JS library or lodash.

My array  is like

```
[{
    2017: {
      a: "100",
      b: "200"
    },
    2018: {
      a: "101",
      b: "202"
    },
    ...
  },

  {
    2017: {
      a: "300",
      b: "400"
    },
    2018: {
      a: "303",
      b: "404"
    },
    ...
  },

  ...
]
```

And I want my result looks like this:

```
[{
  2017: {
    a: "400",
    b: "600"
  },
  2018: {
    a: "404",
    b: "606"
  },

  ...
}]
```

This there a simple way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
let res = [
    {
        2017: {
            a: "100",
            b: "200",
        },
        2018: {
            a: "101",
            b: "202",
        },
    },
    {
        2017: {
            a: "300",
            b: "400",
        },
        2018: {
            a: "303",
            b: "404",
        },
    },
].reduce((acc, el) => {
    Object.keys(el).forEach(year => {
        if(acc[year]){
            acc[year]["a"] += parseInt(el[year]['a']) 
            acc[year]["b"] += parseInt(el[year]['b']) 
        } else {
            acc[year] = {
                a: parseInt(el[year]['a']),
                b: parseInt(el[year]['b']) 
            }
        }
    })
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

the `Object.keys` is necessary only if you might have different years inside the objects on the array, but if those years are always 2017 and 2018, you can remove it

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo much Berto, that works well, and Object.keys is definitely needed in my case, thank you for take care of this case!

Comment: @Miss.Q you're welcome! feel free to mark the question as correct if it solves your problem